# how to stroke "marker-end" of svg path?

Tags: html, css, svg, stroke

I have a SVG path with a marker-end, and I want to stroke both, path and marker-end. The first one is done well, but the marker-end is not stroked by css code. I have tried several times but with no results.

I have tried several ways to stroke the head arrow, including stroking directly the "def" of the svg, adding custom css and class, but none of this worked for me.

The code I used is the given down below:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="arrow">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function deg2rad(angle)
{
  return angle*Math.PI/180.0;
}

function windArrow(speed, angle)
{    
  //var angulo = 0;
  var direction = 90-angle;
  // var speed = 20;
  var x = speed*Math.cos(deg2rad(direction)).toFixed(4);
  var y = speed*Math.sin(deg2rad(direction)).toFixed(4);
  var svgHeader = '<svg version="1.1" id="arrow_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" style="enable-background:new 0 0 493.356 493.356;" xml:space="preserve"><defs><marker id="arrowHead" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="1" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth"><path fill="white" stroke-width="20" d="M0,0 L0,2 L2,1 z" /><path d="M0,0 L0,2 L2,1 z" fill="red"/></marker></defs>';
  var outerArrow = '<g class="outerArrow"> <path marker-end="url(#arrowHead)" d="M50,50 l'+x.toString()+','+y.toString()+'" /></g>';
  var innerArrow = '<g  class="innerArrow"><path marker-end="url(#arrowHead)" d="M50,50 l'+x.toString()+','+y.toString()+'" /></g>';
  var svgFoot = '</svg>';
  return svgHeader+outerArrow + '\n' + innerArrow + svgFoot;
}
document.getElementById('arrow').innerHTML = windArrow(20,45);
```

```
.outerArrow{
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width:6px;
    stroke-linecap:round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
.innerArrow{
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width:2px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

I have made a fiddle with an example:
   https://jsfiddle.net/manespgav/rbua3dhk/

I expect to have the head arrow stroked black, like the straight line of the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - you can fix this by just inlining the styles

```
  var svgHeader = '<svg version="1.1" id="arrow_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" ><defs><marker id="arrowHead" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="1" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth"><path d="M0,0 L0,2 L2,1 z" stroke="none" fill="red"/><path stroke-width=".3" stroke="black" fill="none" d="M0,0 L0,2 L2,1 z" /></marker></defs>';
```

Comment: Your solution don't apply the "stroke" to the base of the head arrow, but it is a good approach and maybe enough for my purposes. Thanks so much mate.

Comment: If you can post an image of what you'd like it to look like - I can give it a second try?

Comment: Your solution is good enough.  The only thing to fix is the base of the head arrow, which hasn't the same "stroke-width" (https://imgur.com/ABjz3Qs). But I don't want to abuse your time. Your answer very acceptable :) Thanks so much